# Change a value in a nested object using useState in reactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm trying to change the value of an object property nested in an array nested inside an object using useState.

State is set as follows:

```
  const [groupState, setGroupState] = useState({
    groupId: uuidv4(),
    content: [{ rowId: uuidv4(), field: '', from: '', to: '' }],
  });
```

I'm trying to change the value of the 'field' property. If I add an entire 'dummy' object with the required value in the required property then it works:

```
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  content: groupState.content.map((item) => {
    if (item.rowId === rowId) {
      return (item = { rowId: uuidv4(), field: value, from: '', to: '' });
    }
  }),
});
```

However, I need to just update the specific property value, not the whole object. My latest effort is the following:

```
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  content: groupState.content.map((item) => {
    if (item.rowId === rowId) {
      return (item.field = value);
    }
  }),
});
```

Which returns the error: "Cannot create property 'field' on string 'user'" - I'm doing somethign wrong but I can't work out what.

Answer (score 1):

Try destructing your item object:

```
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  content: groupState.content.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    field: item.rowId === rowId ? value : item.field,
  })),
});

// Without explicit return
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  content: groupState.content.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, field: item.rowId === rowId ? value : item.field };
  }),
});
```

Comment: Close but no cigar, it works but when you add another row, the field values in previous rows disappear

Comment: Need to find a way of knocking out the else value in the ternary but again, a whole series of errors. %&&%$£! :-)

Comment: No one can guesses how your app works, we answer your specific questions with the information we have.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it, thanks Dennis Vash - just needed a little change:

```
setGroupState({
  ...groupState,
  content: groupState.content.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    field: item.rowId === rowId ? value : item.field,
  })),
```